# How do I retrieve UITableView row number of a UISwitch?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiswitch

I have tried several approaches posted here, but I cannot get my table full of switches to return an index value for the cell of the changed switch. I am creating the view containing the table programmatically (no xib).

**TableSandboxAppDelegate.m** I instantiate the view controller in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` with:

```
...
TableSandboxViewController *sandboxViewController = [[TableSandboxViewController alloc]
    init];
[[self window] setRootViewController:sandboxViewController];
...
```

**TableViewController.h** file reads:

```
@interface TableSandboxViewController : UITableViewController
{
   NSMutableArray *_questionOrder;
   NSMutableArray *switchStates;
}
@end
```

**TableViewController.m** `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` reads:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];

UISwitch *theSwitch = nil;

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
        reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];

    theSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    theSwitch.tag = 100;
    [theSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:)   
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:theSwitch];

} else {
    theSwitch = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
}

if ([[switchStates objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"ON"]) {
    theSwitch.on = YES;
} else {
    theSwitch.on = NO;
}

return cell;
```

**TableViewController.m** `-(IBAction)switchChanged:(UISwitch *)sender` reads:

```
UITableViewCell *theParentCell = [[sender superview] superview];
NSIndexPath *indexPathOfSwitch = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:theParentCell];

NSLog(@"Switch changed at index: %d", indexPathOfSwitch.row);
```

My log result is always "Switch changed at index: 0". I feel like the problem is in that CGPoint line where I've tried combinations of replacements for "sender" ([sender superview], [[sender superview]superview], etc). I don't feel like that line is pointing to the view that displays the table.

What am I doing wrong?

*Note added 10/9, 9:15 EDT:* my goal is to be able to handle about 100 yes/no questions in the table, so reuse is a key. I want to scroll and have the table the state of each switch, as well as be able to retrieve them when leaving the view.

Answer (score 11):

Tags is an okay solution, but a little clumsy because the cells - and therefore their subviews - are continually being reused, changing their rows - and therefore the tags they need.

Instead, I generally keep one of these around:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathWithSubview:(UIView *)subview {

    while (![subview isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell self]] && subview) {
        subview = subview.superview;
    }
    return [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)subview];
}
```

Then when I get an IBAction:

```
- (IBAction)someSubviewAction:(id)sender {

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self indexPathWithSubview:(UIView *)sender];
    // carry on from here
}
```

Comment: I put your indexPathWithSubview method in my `TableSandboxViewController.m` file, and put the `*indexPath` declaration into my `switchChanged:` method, called `indexPath` to my NSLog and still get (null) as the result. Too, when I scroll up and down, the reuse problem of switches randomly switching YES/NO in the view occurs.

Comment: this is very clever!..  but should  while (![subview isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell self]] not be while (![subview isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]  ?

Comment: thinking about it.. same thing!  my mistake, carry on :)

Comment: @danh Could you please explain what the while condition checks for? Sorry, I'm new to this language.

Comment: @Shantanu - The while  walks hierarchy looking for a table view cell parent or ancestor. It stops when it finds one, or when it gets to the root.

Answer (score 6):

You may set switch view tag to row index. Instead of `theSwitch.tag = 100;`

do

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:table cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPth
{
    UISwitch *theSwitch = nil;
    if (cell == nil) {
        ...
        // as per your example
        [cell.contentView addSubview:theSwitch];
    } else {
        theSwitch = subviewWithClass(cell.contentView, [UISwitch class]);
    }

    theSwitch.tag = indexPath.row;
    ...
}
```

Add this helper function to replace `viewWithTag:` call

```
UIView *subviewWithClass(UIView *contentview, Class klass)
{
    for (UIView *view in contentview.subviews)
        if ([view isKindOfClass:klass])
            return view;
    return nil;
}
```

Then retrieve tag, that is a row index now, in your switchChanged function

```
-(IBAction)switchChanged:(UISwitch *)sender {
    NSLog(@"Selected Switch - %d", sender.tag);
    ...
 }
```

Comment: When I replaced my `theSwitch.tag` line with yours, and put your NSLog statement in my `switchChanged:` method, I did get the correct log output of the selected switch row, however as I scrolled up/down, the switches randomly changed in the view between YES/NO. (I have 20 rows displayed in my example). So, somehow the reuse "feature" is drawing new cells by redrawing some of the switches, and their states.

Comment: @dmccall You need to set tag property outside `if(cell==nil)` statement. I updated my answer.

Comment: @dmccall YES/NO problem is unrelated to your original question. Use `-(void)setOn:(BOOL)on animated:(BOOL)animated` function to set state of switches rather than `on` property.

Comment: I think this is misusage of tags. http://doing-it-wrong.mikeweller.com/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-4-uiview.html

Comment: @vikingosegundo A colourful but opinionated blog entry :) Apple doc: "tag - An integer that you can use to identify view objects in your application." Row index is formally an identifier so is used here along the lines of the spec. There are not much technical reasons for or against the use I am suggesting. Boils down to personal prefs. Other suggestions listed here have own drawbacks. The most purist is the one by [Jonah.at](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1607584/jonah-at-godaddy). I personally liked the one by [dahn](http://stackoverflow.com/users/294949/danh). Less code the better.

Comment: *Less code is better* is often a huge mistake. It leads people to mix stuff that doesn't belong together in one class, as it saves some lines of code. It need the right amount of code. Your solution would be OKish — but for sure not great — if you would at least not use magic numbers.

Comment: @vikingosegundo I can't tell what _information_ exactly you were trying to convey in your last comment but thanks anyway :) Cheers.

Comment: i just responded to a useless statement. If you think less code is better: fine for you. I hope I will never be in the situation to need to work with your codes.

Comment: No need to be offensive, @vikingosegundo, really. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If you use something block-based (like https://github.com/brightsoftdev/iOS-Block-Based-Bindings/blob/master/UISwitch%2BBindings.m), you don't need to worry about getting the row, because you can reference the indexPath that is passed into tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: in your block.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @danh, I've come up with this solution using an extention which I've used multiple times.

```
@interface UIView (Find)
- (id)findSuperviewOfClass:(Class)class;
- (NSIndexPath *)findIndexPath;
@end

@implementation UIView (Find)
- (id)findSuperviewOfClass:(Class)class
{
    return [self isKindOfClass:class] ? self : [self.superview findSuperviewOfClass:class];
}

- (NSIndexPath *)findIndexPath
{
    UITableView *tableView = [self findSuperviewOfClass:[UITableView class]];
    return [tableView indexPathForCell:[self findSuperviewOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

for iOS6+ you could maintain a NSMutableArray `queuedSwitches`

in `-tableView:cellForrowAtIndexPath:` you would take a switch, if not empty and places it on the custom cell and assign it to a property. If empty you create a new one.

in `-tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` you would add it to `quededSwitches` and remove it from it cell.

This will just allocate enough switches for visible cells and reuse them.

the switches are all wired up to one action.

```
-(void)switchAction:(UISwitch *)switch 
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:[switch superView]];

    //…
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a subclass of UISwitch and add an indexPath property, then just set the indexPath in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SwitchCell *returnCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SwitchCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    returnCell.switch.indexPath = indexPath;

    return returnCell;
}
```