# UITextField Table View Cells - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, forms, uitableview, uitextfield

I've got a code design question for you all.

I have to build a **dynamic form**, meaning the form is not guaranteed to contain the same fields every time it is loaded.

I am given a list of fields that each form must contain, they are all text inputs. The list I am given is basic JSON describing attributes each field has (i.e. name, isRequired, maxLength, minLength).

I am using UITableViewCell's with UITextField's to create the form. 
In order to validate, and submit the form, I need to keep strong references to each cell, or each cell's text field, so I can get the data that was entered for each field.

How can I create a form on the fly while keeping strong references to each cell (or text field)?

I am happy to answer any clarifying questions you have.

Comment: No, you don't need to keep a strong reference to the cell or the text field, and in fact, you should not do that. The data that's entered should be stored in some sort of data structure, which would be updated from the text field's didFinishEditing delegate method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than keep strong references to the cells, keep a strong reference to a model that represents the cells.  For a table where each row is a text field, the model is an array of strings.  Build it by looping through your JSON adding a string for each form element described by the JSON.

Then your table datasource is that array of strings.  As the text fields' text changes, update the corresponding string (its a little tricky getting from the text field to the right index in the array, but its oft discussed on SO.  My favorite approach is the [@danh solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262361/how-do-i-retrieve-uitableview-row-number-of-a-uiswitch), which can apply to any subview of a cell).

Comment: Are you saying I should update the table view cell each time a character is typed into a text field? That seems a bit intensive.

Comment: Okay, I feel a bit dumb posting that last comment. I understand now, I am simply updating the string in the model and using the model to keep track of the values in the Text Fields. Which is what a model is used for. hahah, thanks bro.

Comment: glad it helped.  check out the uitextfield's delegate protocol.  you can get updated as the text changes, or when its done editing (loses first responder).

Answer (score 0):

You will choose a **dynamic** `tableView` over a **static** one.

As you can see ios sdk is all about `MVC` pattern.

You will to separate your concern the same way, use class models to describe your data.

My biggest advice is you should not rely on the cell at all because they get reused. So don't mix your logic with the interface components.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do this.
What happens when the table scrolls?
You really need a model object which the table reflects, using the table as a model is unwise.  Declare a property of type NSMutableDictionary or array or something, use this to store your data and update it each time a textField is modified