# indexPathForRowAtPoint.row is always returning zero for every cell in a tableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have tableView cells with some custom views in them. When the custom views are touched I need to store the indexPath.row of the cell that the touched view is inside of. This is how I am currently getting the indexPath:

```
@IBAction func bulletGroupPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    let center = sender.center as CGPoint
    let indexPath = self.exercisesTableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(center)!
    self.exercisesTableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)

    println(indexPath.row)
  }
```

I suspect it has something to do with the `!` on the indexPath line, but am not sure exactly what it is. Why does indexPath.row always give me zero on every cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't give you a coded answer in swift, but the point needs to be stated in the coordinate system of the table.  As you have it, the center is stated in the coordinate system of the sender's parent, probably the table view cell.  Use the method [convertPoint:toView:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/convertPoint:toView:) to fix the coordinate system.

Alternatively, you might consider creating a method like the one shown [in my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19262598/294949).  From any view (in your case, the sender), it will walk up the view hierarchy to the first UITableViewCell and report that cell's index path.